# macOS Ventura M1 - poetry install can download numpy-1.21.1

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pip, homebrew, python-poetry

I'm having issues utilizing poetry install to download numpy in my local environment.
within my poetry.lock file - numpy1.21.1 is required.

python version - Python 3.9.6 (default, Oct 18 2022, 12:41:40)
pip3 version - pip 22.3.1 from /Users/test/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
`poetry version - Poetry (version 1.3.1)`
macOs Ventura M1 Pro - 2021 Macbook Pro

I have attempted brew install numpy and it still doesn't work
I have attempted pip3 install numpy==1.21.1 and it still doesn't work

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCqnZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

We can't see the entire error message, but this is likely due to a missing a dependency on the openblas library

```bash
brew install openblas
OPENBLAS="$(brew --prefix openblas)" poetry install
```